# Endothermic Reaction with Specific Details

Tags: safety, heat, chemistry-in-fiction

I need some information for a book I'm writing.

Let's say you're in a confined space, about 8 feet by 8 feet. The area is being heated externally slowly (a few degrees a minute) to about 3,100 degrees F (1700 C). You have ammonium thiocyanate, $\ce{NH4SCN}$, and barium hydroxide octahydrate, $\ce{Ba(OH)2.8H2O}$, 20 g T. You combine them.

Since the room is getting so hot, would the room get equally cold and equally as fast? If you put the chemicals inside of a crate, closed it up, would it take longer to cool off the room? How long would it take for it to do this? Would the cold kill the person inside the room? (Aside from the ammonia burning the lungs and toxic barium because that's easy to fix in a story)

If there's just no way, is there a different chemical reaction that I could have the character use that won't kill her?

Comment: For the crate part, that would depend a lot on the properties of the crate. Also, the important question is the heat flux into the room; although I suppose that could be calculated with some degree of accuracy (neglecting walls, floors, etc.). Another factor that would influence this is if there is air flow in the room.